Two-way repeated measures-input issue
I just started evolving with SPSS a few weeks ago. Let’s say I want to do a statistical test to check the efficiency of 4 different pesticides over 5 weeks (the first week is the control). Every week, we take measurements. I decided to go with the two-way repeated measures ANOVA test (Analyze--> General linear model--> Repeated measurement's selection). My issue is coming up when I have to add the second factor (I added the first factor as a five level). No matter how I insert my data, adding the second factor is impossible.
Week   control  Pes1    Pes2    Pes3    Pest4    
1   2000    100 20  20  300
2   800 10  90  8   60
3   3   80  80  70  400
4   100 80  30  4   200
5   2   3   40  20  300

or
ID  Week    CFU      pESID     MeasurementID
1   Week1    2000   Control 1,00
1   Week1    100    PES1    1,00
……
5   Week5   40  PES2    2,00
5   Week5   20  PES3    3,00
5   Week5   300 pes4    4,00

or
Product week1 week2  week3  week4  week5
1   2000    100 20  20  300
2   800 10  90  8   60
3   3   80  80  70  400
4   100 80  30  4   200
5   2   3   40  20  300

Am I using the wrong test or messing up with the settings? Thanks for any help you can provide!
